# How to answer interview question what did you do undergrad dissertation (for phd interview)

Tags: interview

An undergrad dissertation doesn't consist of much originality, so I don't really know what to say except develop knowledge across this area, like a set of lecture notes.

but I don't think like a set of lecture note sounds too good, although nothing more is really usually expected at undergrad?

thanks

Comment: Well, what DID you do for your undergrad dissertation? It might not be original, but they are asking you to talk about a topic you should know. Did you not write any kind of thesis on a topic?

Comment: Did you do a formal undergrad dissertation/capstone or such? If not, are you asking what to say if you did not have anything formal?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to approach this. What your interviewers want to get from that question is how you present something that you (should) know well.

You *could* just tell them in a very dry manner the goal of the work and what your results were. That will only show them that you did some research and you probably know what you did.

What is probably more impressive is to tell them what kinds of problems you solved and what tools you used to do it (programming, cooperation with other people, trial and error, etc.). From that they will get a glimpse of your work ethics and how excited you are about your work.